# How can I import products into BigCartel

Tags: bigcartel

I have a spreadsheet with product data I want to load into Big Cartel. I have tried to look for an API but found none. How do I do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There's not currently a way to import products or product details to Big Cartel -- all of that information needs to be added manually in the admin.